# How to fix fonts in Xcode4

Tags: xcode4

I do not know why, but soon after fresh installation of Xcode4 my fonts became broken.
Here is an image showing how does it look like. Seems that anti-aliasing is turned off. How can I fix it?

[image: xcode4-ugly-non-antialiased-fonts]

Answer (score 0):

Like most settings, Xcode's fonts are controlled in its Preferences window. Choose Preferences... from the Xcode application menu. Click the appropriately-titled Fonts & Colors panel. Select one, some, or all of the fonts in the list and click the (T) button in the Font chooser field and choose whatever fonts and sizes you wish.

Keep in mind, the Turn Off Font Smoothing option in OS X's General System Preferences panel, if cranked up to, say, 10-12 pixels, might cause the behavior you're seeing at the default font size.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I cant turn on subpixel anti-aliasing from xcode again. I guess I have to write something from terminal to defaults, but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at. Not sure how to help.